# Rule check if field value changed give always true

Tags: rules

I need a rule that checks if the value of a field has been changed by a particular role.

I created a rule with event "After updating existing content".

I added two conditions :

- user has role :

Parameter: User: [site:current-user], Roles: Web Team

- NOT data comparison :

Parameter: Data to compare: [node:body], Data value: [node-unchanged:body]

What I expect is to see the rule fired when a user with role "Web Team" changed the value of the body field of a node.

I expect the rule NOT to be fired when a user with role "Web Team" edit and save a node without changing anything.

And I expect the rule NOT to be fired when a user with no "Web Team" role edit and save a node.

But everytime the user with role "Web Team" edit and save a node, regardless if he changes something or not, the rule is fired.

I tried to change the event in "Before saving content" with no more success.

The log displayed after the save is the following :

```
0 ms Reacting on event Before saving content.
12.599 ms Evaluating conditions of rule test2. [edit]
19.604 ms The condition user_has_role evaluated to TRUE [edit]
23.194 ms The condition data_is evaluated to FALSE [edit]
23.23 ms AND evaluated to TRUE.
```

How AND can be evaluated to TRUE if one of its conditions is evaluated to FALSE?

I did many tests but really don't see how to solve that.

I hove somebody could help me.

Here is the rule exported :

```
{ "rules_test2" : {
    "LABEL" : "test2",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "workflow_rules" ],
    "ON" : { "node_presave" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "user_has_role" : {
          "account" : [ "site:current-user" ],
          "roles" : { "value" : { "5" : "5" } }
        }
      },
      { "NOT data_is" : { "data" : [ "node:body" ], "value" : [ "node-unchanged:body" ] } }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "workflow_rules_set_state" : {
          "node" : [ "node" ],
          "workflow_state" : { "value" : { "11" : "11" } },
          "workflow_comment" : "Title or body modified by webteam. The content should return to contributors for validation."
        }
      },
      { "drupal_message" : { "message" : "node-title = [node:title]\r\n\r\nnode-body = [node:body]\r\n\r\nnode-unchanged-title = [node-unchanged:title]\r\n\r\nnode-unchanged-body = [node-unchanged:body]\r\n" } }
    ]
  }
}
```

Best regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use *:value* for the body or other textarea fields.

The problem is there:

```
{ "NOT data_is" : { "data" : [ "node:body" ], "value" : [ "node-unchanged:body" ] } }
```

Should be:

```
{ "NOT data_is" : { "data" : [ "node:body:value" ], "value" : [ "node-unchanged:body:value" ] } }
```